# Get the ID from Azure table entry

Tags: android, sql, database, azure

How do I get the id from an azure table entry? I'm working on android and need to use the id created by default for a table (when using the azure mobile service) to reference an item in a table. However I am unable to access it? If I add an id attribute to my object being used, I receive an error. Is there some simple way to do something like result.getID?

Comment: This link might help : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated you're using Azure Mobile Services -- there are a couple of Samples available on the Azure Site and this link (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#inserting) has more information about inserting data using Mobile Services.  Specifically, you need a data member called "Id" as these should be generated for you.  The object should have the Id member set following the call to Insert on the service.

I hope that helps

Comment: Yeah thanks so much! I realised last night after tinkering I had made two ID fields for my object and that was causing it to bomb out (I forgot about the original one). After reading the link I realised I just had to remove one and I could use Item.id to get the id.